# Do synthesized properties need pointers in their class interface?

Tags: objective-c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any reason to declare ivars if you're using properties exclusively in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903651/is-there-any-reason-to-declare-ivars-if-youre-using-properties-exclusively-in-o)

This class:

```
@interface MyClass
{
    Something* pointer;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) Something* pointer;
@end

@implementation MyClass
@synthesize pointer
@end
```

Apparently runs the same as:

```
@interface MyClass
@property (nonatomic, retain) Something* pointer;
@end

@implementation MyClass
@synthesize pointer
@end
```

When you create a synthesized property, do you also need a pointer to it in its class interface? I noticed that my program apparently runs the same whether I have the pointer or not. Is it better to have the pointer declared or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any reason to declare ivars if you're using properties exclusively in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4903651/), [Properties and Instance Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3074248/), [Should we declare ivars or let the compiler do it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8047128/), [Property declaration and automatic backing storage](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3238009/), [Do we need to declare ivars?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5864221/)

Comment: Possibly [among others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=declare+ivars+for+properties+%5Bobjc%5D&submit=search).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used to, but you don't anymore. The compiler fills it in automatically for you now, so all you need is to declare the `@property` and `@synthesize` it.

Comment: It is a property of the modern runtime, which has been used in all versions of iOS and since OSX 10.5 on Mac. Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtVersionsPlatforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH106)